# Restrict field type based on another field value

Tags: typescript

Given the following:

```ts
type ActionType = 
    'action1' |
    'action2' |
    'action3';

interface Action {
    type: ActionType;
    value?: number | Date;
}
```

Is there a way in typescript to restrict the type of `value` based on the value of `type`?

For example, if `type` equals `action1` or `action2`, I want the `value` field to be of type `number` but if `type` is `action3` then I want the value to be of type `Date`.

It's probably not possibly but just checking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best chance would probably be to use discriminated unions:

```
type Action = {
    type: 'action1' | 'action2';
    value: number;
} | {
    type: 'action3';
    value: Date;
}
```